# Exporting methods in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class, react-props, react-codemirror

Requirement is to create component whose methods can be accessible to other component so that from through other component we can give alert massage. ( Like toaster)

I know we can do this by following methods:

1. statics - React.createClass or static in es6 class.
2. Using ref of component.

But what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: it would help if you gave us a simple example of what you are trying to do, ( some code)

Comment: I don't have code to share but for example I want something like toaster.

Answer (score 1):

That would look very funky and wouldn't follow the data-down actions-up React approach.

You could use a render prop instead:

```
// App.jsx
<AlertProvider>
  {sendAlert => <Consumer onAlert={sendAlert} />}
</AlertProvider>


// AlertProvider.jsx
export default class AlertProvider extends React.Component {
  sendAlert(msg) { alert(msg); }
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.sendAlert);
  }
}


// Consumer.jsx
export default function Consumer({ onAlert }) {
  return <button onClick={() => onAlert('Boom!')} />
}
```

If you need it to be globally available, consider to use something like Redux.

Comment: But then I have to wrap every component with provider and pass methods to those.

Comment: As said, if you need the same instance to be available in multiple places, take a look at Redux. But, generically, yes, that's the right approach. You want to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: But I don't want my component to be dependent on redux. So that any one can import and use it.